# show that {-∞} and {∞} are Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find the reason that {∞} and {-∞} are Borel sets and closed sets?are these sets are Borel and closed if so then why?

Comment: One-point sets are closed.

Comment: And every closed set is Borel

Comment: If you want to *prove* that $\{\pm \infty\}$ is closed, you need some definition of the topology on $\bar{\Bbb R}$. What does your textbook say about the open sets in $\bar{\Bbb R}$?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Not in every topology.

Comment: @gerw, but yes in *this* topology.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, the usual interval topology.

Comment: They are extended Borel by definition because $\mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}}) = \sigma(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \cup \{\pm \infty\})$. Hence, by construction $\{\pm \infty\} \subset \mathcal{B}(\bar{\mathbb{R}})$.